# Swagger @ApiModelProperty flexibility based on HTTP Request

Tags: java, spring-mvc, swagger, springfox

I'm using Swagger @ApiModelProperty on my fields in a Pojo and have SpringFox to autogen docs. Here is a sample pojo:

```
public class Pojo {
 @ApiModelProperty(value =" some id", hidden = true)
 private final String id;
}
```

I have a endpoint that takes in a Pojo, this endpoint can be /endpoint. This endpoint has both a PUT and POST verb on it. Is there a way with Swagger Annotation or SpringFox Docket config to say on POSTs hide the field 'id' from docs but on PUTs have the field show up on the docs.

I rather not have to make a duplicate class of Pojo just so I can annotate the field to be hidden.

Comment: I appreciate the question and I'm surprised to see this may not be possible...

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's directly possible, but maybe you can solve it in some other way? Here's a couple of alternatives:

1. Make two POJOs but have one extend the other with the `id`-field.
2. Use the same POJO for `POST` and `PUT` but add the `id`-field to the `PUT` in the form of a `@PathVariable`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I think just doing the two POJO route might be the best alternative.